# Access restored but encrypted/locked old wallet (2013 version)

Tags: wallet-recovery, encryption

I Installed Bitcoin Core v25.0.0 and restored my old wallet backup made in 2014 (with bitcoin core version of 2013) successfully. The wallet is shown, status is encrypted and locked.

Trying to unlock the wallet with the passphrase results in this error:

BerkeleyDatabase: Error -30974, can't open database wallet.dat (code -1)

The backup was made on a Linux machine, the recovery on Windows.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be the case and how to resolve this?